# Button that adds rows to HTML table breaks my auto-calculate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to do a table with multiple auto added row with value where the value count automatically. and also show subtotal of values.i try  it, it works in first row but, from second row it doesn't work. i provide a screenshot and my cdes. is there anybody to solve the problem ?

[image]

```js
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i=1;
 $('#add').click(function(){
  i++;
  $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty1" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate1" placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="sum" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
 });
 
 $('#submit').click(function(){  
  $.ajax({
   url:"name.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
   success:function(data)
   {
    alert(data);
    $('#add_name')[0].reset();
   }
  });
 });
 
});
</script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 //this calculates values automatically 
 sum();
 $("#qty1, #rate1").on("keydown keyup", function() {
  sum();
 });
});

function sum() {
   var qty1 = document.getElementById('qty1').value;
   var rate1 = document.getElementById('rate1').value;
   var result = parseInt(qty1) * parseInt(rate1);
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
   }
  }
</script>
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="form-group">
    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
       <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty1" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate1" placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="sum" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" id="allsum" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
        <td></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have multiple input with same id, could be that?

Comment: yes, how can i dynamic my input id ?

Comment: The same way you do this '<tr id="row'+i+'">', you can change '<input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty1"' to '<input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty'+i+'"'...

Same ting to "rate"...

Comment: i try but not work

Comment: will you plz tell me how i rewrite the <script></script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 //this calculates values automatically 
 sum();
 $("#qty1, #rate1").on("keydown keyup", function() {
  sum();
 });
});

function sum() {
   var qty1 = document.getElementById('qty1').value;
   var rate1 = document.getElementById('rate1').value;
   var result = parseInt(qty1) * parseInt(rate1);
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
   }
  }
</script>

Comment: hello, will you plz rewrite  my code for

Comment: hello, will you plz rewrite my code for


<script> $(document).ready(function() { //this calculates values automatically sum(); $("#qty1, #rate1").on("keydown keyup", function() { sum(); }); }); function sum() { var qty1 = document.getElementById('qty1').value; var rate1 = document.getElementById('rate1').value; var result = parseInt(qty1) * parseInt(rate1); if (!isNaN(result)) { document.getElementById('sum').value = result; } } </script>

Comment: sidetopic, make sure you include jQuery before BootStrap.  BootStrap is dependent on it and it may cause issues in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the right idea for creating unique IDs for the `<tr>`s, you just had to use the same technique for the other ids.

Note that you can tell jQuery to select *all IDs that* ***start with*** *certain chars*: `$('[id^=qty], [id^=rate]')`

But when using `.on()`, you must attach the `.on()` to something ABOVE where you will be adding your new rows. That is, if you tell it to watch `$('[id^=qty], [id^=rate]')`, then that's what it will watch -- the one row that already exists. Since nothing is being added inside ***that***, the `.on()` will not trigger. You need to watch an element that already exists and INSIDE WHICH the content will be added. Since new content is being added to `document`, we can use that to trigger the `.on()`. `$('body').on()` will also work... as with anything further down the DOM UP TO the parent where the new content is being added.

This is called [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and is very much worth the two-minutes required to read up on it. You might also want to taken another two minutes and brush up on [event propagation](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-events) and do a quick review of [javascript events.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events). Total time required to read these three articles - about ten minutes. Total time they will save you on this project: potentially, hours.

As an exercise, see how close you can get to the row being added (that is, replace `$(document)` with `$('#dynamic_field')` and see if the `.on()` still triggers.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i=1;
  
 $('#add').click(function(){
  i++;
  $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="sum'+i+'" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
 });
 
 $('#submit').click(function(){  
  $.ajax({
   url:"name.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
   success:function(data)
   {
    alert(data);
    $('#add_name')[0].reset();
   }
  });
 });
 

 //this calculates values automatically 
 $(document).on("keyup", "[id^=qty], [id^=rate]", function() {
    var numm = this.id.match(/\d+/g);
    //var letr = this.id.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
    sum(numm);
 });

function sum(i) {
   var qty1 = $('#qty'+i).val();
   var rate1 = $('#rate'+i).val();
   var result = parseInt(qty1) * parseInt(rate1);
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
    $('#sum'+i).val(result);
        sum_total();
   }
}
function sum_total(){
   $('#allsum').val('Ready for you to write this fn');
   //you do this one - hint: use jQuery $.each() to loop through all the SUM ids, and then update the #allsum input in the #submit_field table.
}

}); //end document.ready
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="form-group">
    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
       <tr id="row1">
        <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty1" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate1" placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="sum1" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="submit_field">
       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" id="allsum" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
        <td></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
```

---

**Per Cale B's sensible suggestion,** here is the same example using classes instead of IDs, where convenient. Note you can use a simple class name rather than a more complicated ***starts with*** selector syntax - *but knowing the starts with selector syntax is pretty cool*.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i=1;
  
 $('#add').click(function(){
  i++;
  $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list qty_cls" /></td><td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list rate_cls" /></td><td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="sum'+i+'" class="form-control name_list sum_cls" disabled /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
 });
 
 $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
 });
 
 $('#submit').click(function(){  
  $.ajax({
   url:"name.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
   success:function(data)
   {
    alert(data);
    $('#add_name')[0].reset();
   }
  });
 });
 

 //this calculates values automatically 
 $(document).on("keyup", ".qty_cls, .rate_cls", function() {
    var numm = this.id.match(/\d+/g);
    //var letr = this.id.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
    sum(numm);
 });

function sum(i) {
   var qty1 = $('#qty'+i).val();
   var rate1 = $('#rate'+i).val();
   var result = parseInt(qty1) * parseInt(rate1);
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
    $('#sum'+i).val(result);
        sum_total();
   }
}
function sum_total(){
   $('#allsum').val('Ready for you to write this fn');
   //you do this one - hint: use jQuery $.each() to loop through all the SUM ids, and then update the #allsum input in the #submit_field table.
}

}); //end document.ready
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="form-group">
    <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
       <tr id="row1">
        <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty1" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate1" placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list qty_cls" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="sum1" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="submit_field">
       <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" id="allsum" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
        <td></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you . but i never use jQuery $.each() before. will you plz help me to write
function sum_total()

i try several time but it not works

Comment: @gibberish really nice example of helping someone to get back on his feet and then letting him do the next step alone

Comment: @ARBhuiyan you can learn about $.each() [in the jQuery API Doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: i make this after add a class to "total" field .  but, it sum only the first row

function sum_total() {
  var total = 0, val;
  $('.sumv').each(function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    val = isNaN(val) || $.trim(val) === "" ? 0 : parseFloat(val);
    total += val;
  });
  $('#allsum').val(Math.round(total));
}

Comment: @cale_b - Good points. Answer updated to incorporate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After some changes, i got an almost solution, but only refreshes each row total when click "Add button". Maybe you can find final solution from this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
  $('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="sum'+i+'" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    sum();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
    $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
  });

  $('#submit').click(function(){    
    $.ajax({
      url:"name.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
      success:function(data)
      {
        alert(data);
        $('#add_name')[0].reset();
      }
    });
  });

});
</script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this calculates values automatically 
  sum();
  $.each($("input[name='qty[]'], input[name='rate[]'"), function() {
    $(this).on("blur", function(e) {
      sum();
    });
  });
});

function sum() {
  $.each($("input[name='qty[]']"), function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    /*console.log(document.getElementById('qty'+id[id.length - 1]).value);
    console.log(document.getElementById('rate'+id[id.length - 1]).value);*/

    var qty1 = document.getElementById('qty'+id[id.length - 1]).value;
    var rate1 = document.getElementById('rate'+id[id.length - 1]).value;
    var result = parseInt(qty1) * parseInt(rate1);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
      document.getElementById('sum'+id[id.length - 1]).value = result;
    }
  });

    }
</script>

<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-group">
        <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty1" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate1" placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="sum1" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" id="allsum" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fully functional test including your grand total.  Note that I made sure each relevant element has a unique ID and that event handlers got added to each element as it was created using those unique IDs.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
var i=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="qty['+i+']" id="qty'+i+'"  placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list qty" /></td><td><input type="text" name="rate['+i+']" id="rate'+i+'"  placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list rate" /></td><td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="sum'+i+'" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        $('#qty'+i+', #rate'+i).change(function() {
            sum(i)
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
        sum_total();
    });

    $('#submit').click(function(){      
        $.ajax({
            url:"name.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $('#add_name')[0].reset();
            }
        });
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    //this calculates values automatically 
    sum(0);
});

function sum(i) {
    var qty1 = document.getElementById('qty'+i).value;
    var rate1 = document.getElementById('rate'+i).value;
    var result = parseInt(qty1) * parseInt(rate1);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('sum'+i).value = result;
    }
    sum_total();
}
function sum_total() {
    var newTot = 0;
    for (var a=0; a<=i ; a++) {
        aVal = $('#sum'+a);
        if (aVal && aVal.length) { newTot += aVal[0].value ? parseInt(aVal[0].value) : 0; }
    }
    document.getElementById('allsum').value = newTot;
}
</script>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name="qty[0]" id="qty0" onchange="sum(0)" placeholder="Enter your Qty" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="rate[0]" id="rate0" onchange="sum(0)" placeholder="Enter your Rate" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="total[0]" id="sum0" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
                                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Total</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" id="allsum" class="form-control name_list" disabled /></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```